# Is there a character limit to what Scrapy returns?

Tags: scrapy

If I go into the scrapy shell with

```
scrapy shell http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60956-San_Antonio_Texas-Hotels.html
```

and call

```
hxs.select('//title/text()').extract
```

I get

```
data=u'San Antonio Hotels: Compare 345 Hotels i'
```

which is 40 characters counting the spaces. Is this a limit that goes beyond Scrapy and I should look out for this also in future unicode dealings?

Answer (score 2):

u have to enclose the extract function as

```
hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()
```

now you will be able to get the full text

Answer (score 1):

```
hxs.select("//title/text()").extract()
```

will return the full string

using it without () probably returns a representation of the object, which is limited (for inspection) to 40 characters.